# Return value from prior year Spark sql

Tags: sql, apache-spark-sql, partition-by, spark-window-function

I have the following table:

| YearMonth | value |
| --- | --- |
| 202101 | 5 |
| 202102 | 7 |
| .... | 10 |
| 202201 | 4 |

I need to create third column with the value from the previous year.
When I have 202201 there should be valuePriorYear equals 5 (value from 202101).
I've tried with the lag and over partition but I'm able select only value from the previous month

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's assume you have this dataset:

```scala
val df = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(Seq(
  (202101, 5),
  (202102, 7),
  (202004, 8),
  (202104, 6),
  (202201, 0)
)).toDF("YearMonth", "value")
```

You can add to `YearMonth` the value of `100` (since you are working with yearweeks) and rename your `value` (I don't really know your case, but for the sake of clarity).

```scala
val df2 = df
  .withColumn("YearMonth", col("YearMonth").plus(100))
  .withColumnRenamed("value", "value2")
```

Then finally join back:

```scala
val df3 = df.join(df2, Seq("YearMonth"), "left")
```

Final result:

```
+---------+-----+------+
|YearMonth|value|value2|
+---------+-----+------+
|202004   |8    |null  |
|202101   |5    |null  |
|202102   |7    |null  |
|202104   |6    |8     |
|202201   |0    |5     |
+---------+-----+------+
```

I hope this is useful, good luck!